# How to implement uisearchcontroller to retrieve data from server side with a post request

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

Please help me how to make a uisearchcontroller to send a post request about search text with a task to get a json request and display it.  I have completed PHP and JSON side but stuck in search controller. I found samples in internet about uisearchcontroller but all of them have their arrays in the code.  None of them get data from server side..

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use `dispatch_async()` to call your server API in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`. When the server request returns, update your internal array of results in the table data source and call `reloadData` on the `UITableView`.

Something like:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        results = remote_api.call(searchText)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.results = results
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }    
}
```

Note that server requests may return out of order. You might want to check for this.

Comment: Actually, your answer seems exactly what I need. But, I get data with asynchronus HTTP Request and return values to three arrays (user id, username, user image).  So, can you please give me more detail that how can I return these arrays with "results = remote_api.call(searchText)".